# Mysql database error in scritpt

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me in solving this issue about my database, i'm having errors when i try to import my database.

```
> A right parenthesis was expected (near ")" at position 282)

 Database: `optima` -- -- -------------------------------------------------------- -- --  

Table `zm7pa_assets`

Structure -- 

 CREATE TABLE `zm7pa_assets` ( `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', 
           `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT )

Syntaxe error near ')' at line 14.
```

Here is the table script:

```
CREATE TABLE `zm7pa_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
) ;
```

Comment: You have COMMENT without comment string. Remove COMMENT on the end or add comment string like in id column `CREATE TABLE zm7pa_assets (  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', parent_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0');`

Comment: I'm havin another error when i remove COMMENT. Send me your email so that i can send you the database script file to check

Comment: I don't know what error you have but maybe it is default value '0' is string but type is int, try to remove ' `CREATE TABLE zm7pa_assets ( id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', parent_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remove the COMMENT since there is no comment :D

```
CREATE TABLE zm7pa_assets ( 
   id        int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', 
   parent_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  
   );
```

Comment: I removed the COMMENT but other errors appear. The database is a joomla web site database. you will need the sql file to solve the problem

Comment: Here is my web site link  http://cenitech.net/   you will see the errors

Comment: @Boubacar this error does not apply to the zm7pa_assets table. The session memory is in DB in the table "zm7pa_session. But this table does not exist anymore.

Comment: Thats the reason why i asked you send me you email address so that i can send you the database file to check out the problem